# Android java status bar color not being transparent while using ScrollView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, statusbar

I've tried lot of methods to make status bar transparent when using Scroll view.
Without scrollView, I change status bar color transparent easily in theme.xml file.
but no methods working for scrollView:(

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".LogInActivity">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <LinearLayout...>

</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

LogInActivity.java

```
package com.project.appname;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;


public class LogInActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_Talkrr_Status);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_log_in);

        Window window = getWindow();
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
        window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    }
}
```

themes.xml

```
<style name="Theme.AppName.Status">

    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>

</style>
```

Comment: Do you want to add the transparency on scrolling? Or just when the activity is loaded?

Comment: yes I want to add transparency while scrolling